# Порядок запуска потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста почему идет запуск методов в потоках именно в таком порядке. Вот код:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class a 
{
    object o = new object();
    public void Test()
    {
        lock (o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            Monitor.Wait(o);
            Console.WriteLine("Stop");
        }
    }
    public void UnLock()
    {
        lock(o)
        Monitor.Pulse(o);
        Console.WriteLine("Unlock");
        for(int x = 0; x <10; x++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
class b
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a A = new a();
        Thread t = new Thread(A.Test);
        t.Start();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(A.UnLock);
        t1.Start();
    }
}
```

Я ожидаю что вначале запустится `Test`, потом написав слово `Start` он останавливается, потом запускается метод `UnLock` и при вызове в нем `Pulse()` метод `Test` не должен продолжать свое дело, так как `Pulse()` не снимает блокировку с объекта, однако как только вызывается `Pulse()`, то несмотря на заблокированный объект в методе `Unlock`, метод `Test` начинает продолжать свое дело. Почему так?? То есть я ожидаю вывод такой

```
Start
Unlock
0....9
Stop
```

а получается

```
Start
Unlock
Stop
0....9
```

То есть видно, что метод `Pulse` говорит о освобождении объекта блокировки, и не смотря на то что он не освободился по факту, метод `Test` продолжает свою работу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в коде две проблемы. Первая - неправильный отступ. У вас сейчас на самом деле написано следующее:

```
public void UnLock()
{
    lock(o)
    {
        Monitor.Pulse(o);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Unlock");
    for(int x = 0; x <10; x++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

как указал Pavel Mayorov, вы освобождаете лок сразу же после вызова `Pulse`.

Вторая - само предположение, что второй поток будет запущен позже. Это многопоточность, и нет никаких гарантий что `Test` начнет выполнятся до `UnLock`. Даже починив `lock`, при определенном положении звезд, вы вполне можете получить вывод:

```
Unlock
0....9
Start
```

и зависание на `Wait`.

Answer (score 2):

Сразу после вызова `Pulse` вы освобождаете блокировку, выходя из блока `lock(o)` - вот первый поток и продолжает работу.

Comment: Но ведь, если я правильно понял, то Pulse  не освобождает блокировку, а просто сообщает об ее освобождении, но блокировка висит дальше, освобождает только Wait. Или я ошибаюсь ??

Comment: Освобождает блокировку еще и выход из блока `lock`.

Answer (score 2):

Из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Поток, который в данный момент владеет блокировкой указанного объекта,
>   вызывает этот метод для сообщения следующему в очереди потоку о
>   блокировке. При получении импульса ожидающий поток перемещается в
>   очередь готовности. Когда поток, вызвавший метод Pulse, освобождает
>   блокировку, следующий поток в очереди готовности (который
>   необязательно является потоком, получившим импульс) получает
>   блокировку.

Т.е. поскольку вы берете лок только на вызов метода `Pulse()`, то `Test()` продолжает работу сразу после того, как освобождается блокировка в `Unlock()`. Чтобы исправить это, блокировку надо брать на весь код:

```
public void UnLock()
{
    lock(o)
    {
        Monitor.Pulse(o);
        Console.WriteLine("Unlock");
        for(int x = 0; x <10; x++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

(И логичнее будет вызывать `Pulse()` после цикла.)

---

Но у вас есть еще одно неверное предположение: что метод `Test()` будет запущен раньше, чем `Unlock()`. Это необязательно так. Первым может запуститься метод `Unlock()`.